# Can I upgrade linux-base to newer major version?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I'm on Trusty and would like to continue installing the newest mainline kernels. These started to depend on linux-base >= 4.5, while Trusty only has linux-base 3.5 in its PPAs. Is it safe to get linux-base from a xenial PPA and install it on my trusty? Could it break something?

Comment: @karel I'm specifically asking about linux-base, which is a package I don't know... it's not linux-image* or linux-headers* which are the traditional kernel upgrade packages.

Comment: I think you mean “repository” instead of “[PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to download linux-base 4.5 from the official Ubuntu [Download Page for linux-base_4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1_all.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/linux-base/download) and double-click the linux-base_4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1_all.deb that you downloaded to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center. There won't be any dependency problems either.

Comment: Do you have any "evidence" for this claim? I mean, it may not only be about the formal dependencies od the DEB package...

Comment: Okay, I looked into the source package for linux-base, and it seems it's just a few perl scripts, which really should not make the system unbootable. They seem to be only used in the install phase of new kernels. I'm gonna give it a try.